# What Hibernate annotations am I missing?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, annotations

I'm brand new to Hibernate, and I'm trying to get a fairly simple Hibernate code snippet to work. After reading the tutorials, I'm totally choking on the full implementation.

For one, when it comes to the `hbm2ddl.auto` property, I'm setting it to `validate` because I just don't like the idea of Hibernate creating my table structure (I'm old fashioned; perhaps that will change as I become more comfortable with Hibernate though). In any event, here's the table I just created on a MySQL server:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id                      INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
    email                   VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    title                   VARCHAR(25),
    first_name              VARCHAR(100),
    middle_name             VARCHAR(100),
    last_name               VARCHAR(100),
    suffix                  VARCHAR(100),

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Thise corresponds to the following POJOs/entities in my app's code:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="my_db", name="users")
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    // ???
    private PersonName personName;

    public User(final String email, final PersonName personName) {
        super();

        setEmail(email);
        setPersonName(personName);
    }

    // Getters and setters omitted for brevity...
}

public abstract class BaseName {
    public abstract String toName();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return toName();
    }
}

public class PersonName extends BaseName {
    private String title;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private String suffix;

    public PersonName(final String title, final String firstName, final String middleName, final String lastName, final String suffix) {
        super();

        setTitle(title);
        setFirstName(firstName);
        setMiddleName(middleName);
        setLastName(lastName);
        setSuffix(suffix);
    }

    // Getters and setters omitted for brevity...
}
```

What annotations/config do I need to add so that `User#personName` gets persisted as an embedded `PersonName` object inside the `users` table? In other words, `User` is an entity and contains a `PersonName` as an embedded objects (non-entity).

Also, any other obvious annotations I'm missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by user @Snow Blind, [Embedded objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e714) are what you want.

Let's start with class `PersonName`:

```
@Embeddable
public class PersonName extends BaseName {
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    private String middleName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "suffix")
    private String suffix;

    // ...
}
```

Now add the `@Embedded` tag here:

```
// ...

@Embedded
private PersonName personName;

// ...
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can check the title `2.2.2.4. Embedded objects (aka components)` in docs:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-property